# Where does Domino server 6.5 store synchronized address books?

Tags: ibm-domino, lotus-notes

We have a user whose profile was migrated from our local domino server to a server at our home office after she moved to a remote office. Her address book file (locally stored in Notes 6.5) has been synchronized and she has access to all her contacts via her Blackberry.

She is now using a thin client/VDI setup at the new office and there are no addresses showing in her personal address book in Notes. Helpdesk has no clue (as usual) except to suggest that I copy the address book database file from her old computer in our office to her network drive (where Notes is now configured). Problem with this is that I repurposed her computer already and so there is no local address book database file to copy.

But she has all contacts on her BB and so we no nothing is lost. Prior to moving, she'd synchronized her address book and so everything is up on a server, somewhere.

So, after fighting with the helpdesk she calls me and tells them what they told her, and I suggest using Synchonize Address Book on her new system in order to simply download the addresses to her client and local address book database.

When she attempts to do this, she receives an error stating that only the database owner is allowed to do this. Which means I need to go to that database on the server and make sure the ACL on the database agrees with her system configuration.

One problem: I can't find where the sychronized address book databases are stored on a domino server.

Do you know?

Or, is there something else entirely that I ought to be looking for or configuring to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Synchronize Address Book action actually copies contacts into the user's mail database itself.  There are several views like "($Contacts)", "($Users)" or "($VIMPeople)" in the mail database that Domino Web Access (and newer versions of BB) uses to display Contacts on the web.

Try just giving her Manager access to her own mail file and then use the synchronize action again.

Comment: That would make sense, I suppose. Insofar as Domino and Notes are capable of making sense. I'm checking it out right now with the user.

Comment: Ok. She's a manager on her mailfile now. She was a manager on her mailfile when she was here in our office. But she moved to another branch office and they migrated her database from our mailserver to the home office server to speed up her email access a little. I haven't gotten her to test yet. I'll report back when she does.

Comment: Ok, the user confirmed the help desk did something and got their setup working. So I was unable to confirm this was the correct solution. However, I'll mark it as such as it is the only solution offered.